# Configuring powershell core from .net core to provision a one drive

Tags: powershell, .net-core, onedrive, powershell-core

I'm attempting to provision a one drive in a dotnet core app using powershell core.  Running powershell I've been able to successfully provision a one drive from the powershell command line following the directions provided below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/pre-provision-accounts

Running it programatically in .net core however it looks like it uses a separate powershell that's bundled into .net core 2.1

I believe the unsuccessful in app runs are due to the powershell bundled with core not being setup correctly, namely the first 3 steps in the link above:

1.Download the latest SharePoint Online Management Shell.

2.Download and install the SharePoint Online Client Components SDK.

3.Connect to SharePoint Online as a global admin or SharePoint admin in Office 365. To learn how, see Getting started with SharePoint Online Management Shell.

**How do I set up the powershell that gets run by my application to mirror those steps above?**

My code looks like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace PowerShellApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(
            {
                ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(<scriptLocation>))
                    .Invoke();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How do I achieve these steps when executing within a .net core application

The powershell script I"m running is below and also within the link above:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
 This script adds an entry for each user specified in the input file 
 into the OneDrive provisioning queue

.DESCRIPTION
 This script reads a text file with a line for each user. 
 Provide the User Principal Name of each user on a new line.
 An entry will be made in the OneDrive provisioning queue for each
 user up to 200 users.
.EXAMPLE
 .\BulkEnqueueOneDriveSite.ps1 -SPOAdminUrl https://contoso-    admin.sharepoint.com -InputfilePath C:\users.txt 
.PARAMETER SPOAdminUrl
 The URL for the SharePoint Admin center
 https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
.PARAMETER InputFilePath
 The path to the input file.
 The file must contain 1 to 200 users
 C:\users.txt
.NOTES
 This script needs to be run by a global or SharePoint administrator in Office 365
 This script will prompt for the username and password of the administrator
#>
param
(
    #Must be SharePoint Administrator URL
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $SPOAdminUrl,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $InputFilePath
)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")     | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.R    untime") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.U    serProfiles") | Out-Null
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SPOAdminUrl)
$Users = Get-Content -Path $InputFilePath
if ($Users.Count -eq 0 -or $Users.Count -gt 200)
{
    Write-Host $("Unexpected user count: [{0}]" -f $Users.Count) -    ForegroundColor Red
    return 
}
$web = $ctx.Web
Write-Host "Enter an admin username" -ForegroundColor Green
$username = Read-Host
Write-Host "Enter your password" -ForegroundColor Green
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$password )
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$loader =     [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.ProfileLoader]::GetProfileLoader($ctx)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$loader.CreatePersonalSiteEnqueueBulk($Users)
$loader.Context.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host "Script Completed"
```

Comment: Do you want to translate powershell to .net?

Comment: We actually had an implementation of that, but had an issue with the dll's not loading correctly, which is why we switched to the Powershell Core execution.  If I could just figure out how to configure the powershell that .net core executes that would solve our issues.

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear on what the problem is. Is it about switching your script/snippet from powershell to powershell core?

Comment: Correct, so the link above has a couple of steps that looks like it installs a couple things to my local machine, the sharepoint online management shell, and the sharepoint client sdks.  In that installation, it configures the powershell on my machine to use the new libraries. The third step is to associate that shell with an admin account.  When I execute my code however, it looks like .net core has it's own instance of powershell that isn't configured.  I know this because when I run the a command to get the version of powershell locally vs in the dotnet code, they return different versions.

Comment: Are you going to run this app on linux? Wondering why are you switching to core

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid SP Online management Shell has dependencies from .Net Framework and will not work with Core ([check this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Announcing-availability-of-SharePoint-Online-Management-Shell/ba-p/241370)).
From the other side that module seemed to be a wrapper on top of their REST API. So if you want to integrate it with Core app, you may try to replace it with HTTP requests. Check this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx#bk_ProfileLoader)

Also, below is a base powershell script to work with those REST API endpoints. I tested this one on my site:

```
$baseUrl = "http://sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite/_api"
$cred = Get-Credential

# retreive digest
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$baseUrl/contextinfo" -Method Post -Credential $cred -SessionVariable sp
$digest = ([xml]$r.content).GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestvalue

# calling endpoint

$endpoint = "sp.userprofiles.profileloader.getprofileloader/getuserprofile"

$head = @{
 "Accept" = "application/json;odata=verbose"
 "X-RequestDigest" = $digest
 }

$re = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$baseUrl/$endpoint" -Headers $head -Method Post -WebSession $sp

Write-Host $re.Content
```

This is a snippet for createpersonalsiteenqueuebulk, but I can't test it since I'm not domain admin. Hope it will work for you

```
 #--- sample 2 (didn't test it since I'm not domain admin). Might need separate session/digest

$endpoint2 = "https://<domain>-admin.sharepoint.com/_api/sp.userprofiles.profileloader.getprofileloader/createpersonalsiteenqueuebulk"

$head = @{
 "Accept" = "application/json;odata=verbose"
 "X-RequestDigest" = $digest
 }

$body =  "{ 'emailIDs': ['usera@domain.onmicrosoft.com', 'userb@domain.onmicrosoft.com'] }"
$re2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$endpoint2" -Headers $head -body $body -Method Post -WebSession $sp
Write-Host $re2.Content
```